# Electron render glitch

Tags: javascript, html, css, rendering, electron

I'm making an Electron app, in which I scroll inside a div-element, I have two types of elements in this div (both have `position: absolute`):

1. Objects  (div)
2. Lines    (canvas)

The idea is that you can place objects and connect them with lines, but for some strange reason, when I change **anything** with the

`let ctx = document.getElementById(this.id).getContext("2d");`
variable, the Object elements suddenly look like they have `position: fixed`, even thought they don't.
 
It acts all fine, and well, the only strange thing is that it isn't rendered where it should be, and sometimes disappears when I scroll further.

I'm pretty sure this isn't a bug in my code because the chromium-dev-tools show a hit-box on the place it's supposed to be.

And it gets even weirder, when I open it in a normal browser, for example google Chrome (build on Chromium just like Electron), it works fine. 

Does anyone know what the problem is?, Maybe in the main process?

EDIT:

If done some more research and I found out the following:

1. the glitch only happens when (at least) one of the objects is out of the natural viewing port 
   (`mainDiv.scrollTop = 0; and mainDiv.scrollLeft = 0;` and then what you can see)
2. The hit-boxes work and are in the correct space, only the rendering is strange.

HTML:

lineobject: `<canvas class='contentFrame_line' id='/*lineId*/'></canvas>`

CSS:

`.contentFrame_line {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}`

CODE:
(all of this code is in a custom 'line'-type object)

```
this.update = function() {
    //get the 'Objects', (CF.getObjectById gives the custom Object by it's Id)
    let fromObject = CF.getObjectById(this.fromObjectId);
    let toObject = CF.getObjectById(this.toObjectId);


    // calculate the fromX, fromY, toX and toY 
    let fromX = fromObject.x;
    let fromY = fromObject.y;
    let toX = toObject.x;
    let toY = toObject.y;


    //calculate the minX, minY, maxX and maxY
    let minX = Math.min(fromX, toX);
    let minY = Math.min(fromY, toY);
    let maxX = Math.max(fromX, toX);
    let maxY = Math.max(fromY, toY);


    //set the canvas width, height, resolution and position
    let width = maxX - minX;
    let height = maxY - minY;

    this.html = document.getElementById(this.id);
    this.html.style.width = width + "px";
    this.html.style.height = height + "px";
    this.html.width = width;
    this.html.height = height;

    this.html.style.left = minX + "px";
    this.html.style.top = minY + "px";

    //draw the line on the canvas
    this.draw(fromX - minX, fromY - minY, toX - minX, toY - minY);
}

this.draw = function(fromX, fromY, toX, toY) {
    this.html = document.getElementById(this.id);
    this.ctx = this.html.getContext("2d");

    this.ctx.beginPath();

    this.ctx.moveTo(this.html.width / 2, 0);
    this.ctx.lineTo(this.html.width / 2, this.html.height);

    this.ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question should contain [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I know, but I can't run Electron in the browser, because it works fine when I run the same code in a normal browser. So how can I recreate the problem?

Comment: A good starting point would be to give us the CSS/JS/HTML that affects the region since it is hard to have a imaginary render working in your mind :P I had issues with SVG's in the past so i think i can help you once i have enough information

Comment: I am not sure if a solution has been reached here, but for what it's worth, I have had positioning issues when running cypress.io tests in electron. fixed position containing elements seem to be hiding their relatively positioned child elements.